# How do I get stacked inline-block divs to touch the div above it?

Tags: javascript, html, css

[image]

I have a bunch of divs each with a random height but the same width arranged in a container. I set the `vertical-align : top` to make sure that each div is aligned to the top of the container but there are still spaces between the divs and the one's beneath it. I would like all the divs to touch each other.

HTML:

`<div className="interestoptions"  onClick = {(event) = {this.interestClicked(event);}}></div>`

CSS:

```
`.interestoptions{
      width: 30%;
      display: inline-block;
      border-radius: 5px;
      border: 1px solid whitesmoke;
      vertical-align: top;
    }`
```

Comment: There's no way you looked at that picture you included.

Comment: What do you mean?

Comment: not everyone can clearly see a whitesmoke over a white coloration

Comment: Include the markup